# Does electron.io have access to run git commands?

Tags: desktop-application, electron

I'd like to use electron (http://electron.atom.io/) to build an authoring tool for a static website. This will allow my non-developer teammates to edit static website content, without needing me to build a giant CMS.

I'll teach them a hand full of git concepts and markdown, and then build them a little desktop app they can use to update the site's static content.

But! I can't for the life of me figure out if electron gives you access to running terminal commands. Not to mention, can I package git as a dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Node's child process API to spawn external processes from your Electron app, but it may be a better idea to use `libgit2` instead via the [`nodegit` module](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit).

Comment: You rock!! Thanks : ) I've done the former before, so that's a familiar option, but I like your suggestion!